# Probabilities/combinations problem.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am stuck for $4$ days in the following problem:

We have $r$ containers and $n$ balls. Every container can contain from $0$ to $n$ balls. How many combinations exist to place the balls in the containers? Keep in mind that every ball has a different colour.

What I have done up to now:

If we have $2$ balls let's say one red and one green. If we consider that placing red-green and green-red is the same combination then the combinations are given from $n^{r}$. But to my understanding green-red and red-green are supposed to be considered as different combinations. So I have searched extensively and I can't find anywhere any formula to find those combinations. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each ball, it has $r$ different choice, and we have $n$ balls. Isn't it $r^n$?